# Simple Java GIS Editor

Tags: java, frameworks, gis

I'm looking for a library/application that would give me a good starting point for an application that will needed to:

- display a (big) rail/street network on a map (geographically limited to central Europe)
- rail/street network has its custom graph data structure (no standards we could benefit from)
- standard interaction with map: zoom/pan
- interaction with network: remove/add nodes and edges. move nodes.

Implementation preferably in Java. Thats's it ;)

Would love to hear your suggestions on this topic!
Thanks very much,
Patrick

Comment: Do you bear in mind desktop or web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) which is a full-featured geospatial server based on the [GeoTools library](http://www.geotools.org/).
Besides, you could check all the other projects hosted by [OSGeo](http://www.osgeo.org/).

As for standards, there are quite a few that you could benefit from, developed by [OGC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Geospatial_Consortium#Standards).

Answer (score 0):

Give [**uDig**](http://udig.refractions.net/) a shoot. Open source and in Java.

Fulfils your criteria of display and interaction (I tried with relatively large vector data, not sure about raster performance though).

I cannot really say how it works with network datasets, but with enough programming skills you could probably hack your way with some custom plugins. Here is a [starting point](http://udig.github.com/docs/dev/tool_plugin_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting project worth checking out is [Degree](https://www.deegree.org/) which is in [OsGeo](https://www.osgeo.org/) endorsed projects just like Geoserver.